How do I plot my predictions for my Multiclass model?
I have this code and I want to plot my predictions I always get an ValueError, I got my data from Kaggle:
def plot_predictions(train_data=X_tr,
                     train_labels=y_tr,
                     test_data=X_t,
                     test_labels=y_t,
                     predictions=None):
  
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))


    plt.scatter(train_data[:,0], train_labels[:,0], c="b", s=4, label="Training data")

    plt.scatter(test_data, test_labels, c="g", s=4, label="Testing data")

    if predictions is not None:
        plt.scatter(test_data, predictions, c="r", s=4, label="Predictions")
        
        correct = (predictions == test_labels).sum().item()
        total = test_labels.size(0)
        accuracy = correct / total
        plt.title(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")

    # Show the legend
    plt.legend(prop={"size": 14})
    plt.show()

The error is
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1070], line 1
----> 1 plot_predictions();

Cell In[1069], line 10
      7 plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
      9 # Plot training data in blue
---> 10 plt.scatter(train_data[:,0], train_labels[:,0], c="b", s=4, label="Training data")
     12 # Plot test data in green
     13 plt.scatter(test_data, test_labels, c="g", s=4, label="Testing data")

File ...:3684, in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, data, **kwargs)
   3665 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.scatter)
   3666 def scatter(
   3667     x: float | ArrayLike,
   (...)
   3682     **kwargs,
   3683 ) -> PathCollection:
-> 3684     __ret = gca().scatter(
   3685         x,
   3686         y,
   3687         s=s,
   3688         c=c,
   3689         marker=marker,
...
   4654 if s is None:
   4655     s = (20 if mpl.rcParams['_internal.classic_mode'] else
   4656          mpl.rcParams['lines.markersize'] ** 2.0)

ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Here are the tensor shapes:
X_tr.size() # torch.Size([275, 24])
X_t.size() # torch.Size([69, 24])
y_tr.size() # torch.Size([1, 275])
y_t.size() # torch.Size([69, 1])

I  tried reshaping, slicing, squeeze, unsqueeze, but nothing worked

What do X_tr, X_t, y_tr, and y_t correspond to with regards to your function inputs?

Your X_tr and y_tr shape isn't consistent, transposing your y_tr should be able to fix the problem.
